# Eclipse show context menu for specific types using visibleWhen

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

So I am developing an Eclipse View which visualizes an `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree` of my custom type `my.application.Term` using an `CheckStateChangedEvent.ContainerCheckedTreeViewer`. `Term` is an interface extending `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject`.

I want to display a context menu containing several commands only when clicking on a `Term`.

```
<menuContribution
    locationURI="popup:my.application.View">
    <command
        commandId="my.application.renameterm"
        tooltip="Rename this term">
         <visibleWhen
            checkEnabled="false">
            <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
                <iterate
                    ifEmpty="false">
                    <instanceof value="my.application.Term"/>
                </iterate>
            </with>
        </visibleWhen>
    </command>  
</menuContribution>
```

I have tried several things like leaving out the `<iterate>` element or the `checkEnabled`. However, independent of what I am trying, the context menu shows everytime I am right-clicking inside my view and not only when clicking on a `Term`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Stephan, as an aside, does Shift+F10 succeed in opening your context menu?

Answer (score 0):

To use `activeMenuSelection` your tree must be the selection provider for your view. You set this with:

```
getSite().setSelectionProvider(provider);
```

where `provider` implements `ISelectionProvider`. The JFace `TreeViewer` already implements `ISelectionProvider` so this is what is normally used. If you are just using `Tree` you will have to write your own.

Comment: I might have missed that detail in my question (just added it), but I am already using an `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.ContainerCheckedTreeViewer` which is an `TreeViewer`.

Comment: And have you called `setSelectionProvider`? What does your tree content provider return as the objects for the tree - it is these objects that will be tested by `instanceof`?